# Slow Calculating Assignment Function in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to assign accounts to sales reps based on multiple criteria, using a lookup table and multiple dimension variables (state, country, division, etc)

The lookup table has a column for each of the inputs (Country, state, division, vertical, focus), as well as a column for the person who should be assigned. there are ~2400 rows in the assign table.

I'm passing the function to each row of my data using df.apply and a lambda function on the row.

The code I have pasted below works but is taking over an hour to calculate on 300k rows. I am looking mainly for general direction towards making the calculation more efficient. I sense I should try to vectorize the lookup but:

1. I'm not sure how to do so.
2. I'm not sure whether or not it's possible with one-off if-statements in the function.

The code is as follows:

```
# Assigns accounts to reps based on their current status, country, state, division,
# & vertical. Slightly different rules used for Acute Enterprise, as they don't
# have AM's and Sales broken out
def assign_accounts (cust_type, record_type, top_vert_arr, country, state, division, vertical, top_parent, opp_owner):

    if top_parent == 'INACTIVE - DO NOT CALL':
        return 'Joe Schmoe'

    # Check on whether the customer has joined in the last 6 months
    elif opp_owner == opp_owner:
        return opp_owner


    elif (vertical == 'Acute') & (division == 'Enterprise'):
        try:
            rep_name = assign.loc[(assign['country'] == country) &
                                (assign['state'] == state) &
                                (assign['division'] == division) &
                                (assign['vertical'] == vertical) &
                                (assign['product'] == 'Learning')]
            return rep_name['rep'].iloc[0][:]

        except:
            return 'No Map1'

    # All non-customers going to New Sales reps
    elif (top_vert_arr == 0) :
            try:
                rep_name = assign.loc[(assign['country']== country) &
                            (assign['state'] == state) &
                            (assign['division'] == division) &
                            (assign['vertical'] == vertical) &
                            (assign['focus'] == 'New')]
                return rep_name['rep'].iloc[0][:] # returns name as text
            except:
                return 'No Map5'        

    # All customers going to Account Manager assignment 
    else:
        try:
            rep_name = assign.loc[(assign['country']== country) &
                            (assign['state'] == state) &
                            (assign['division'] == division) &
                            (assign['vertical'] == vertical) &
                            (assign['focus'] == 'AM')]
            return rep_name['rep'].iloc[0][:] # returns name as text
        except:
            return 'No Map3'


#New rep assignments added to data
accounts['new_assignment'] = accounts.apply(lambda row : assign_accounts(row['type'], row['record_type'], row['top_vert_arr'], row['country'], row['bill_state'], row['division'],
                            row['short_final_vertical'], row['top_parent'], row['opp_owner']), axis = 1)
```

Any directional help here would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please format your function as code - https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Are you using a Pandas DataFrame? Would it be possible to include a minimal example of the DataFrame that would work with the code? - something we could use to test with? ... [mcve]

Comment: StackOverflow works best when dealing with specific, narrow problems that can be isolated to a single piece of code. Advice on improving working code is often a better fit for our sister site [codereview.se] -- but before posting there, see [A Guide To Code Review For Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/155649)., and note their additional requirements carefully.